# Error vb.net - Operation must use an updateable query

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, windows-7, unc

I have a data driven application coded in VB 2008 & ms access database.
The application was working fine with Windows XP (SP3 32bit).
But after upgrade of OS from windows xp to windows 7 (both 32 bit) I started receiving this error.

After trials and errors I come to the conclusion that this is all because of connection string I am using which is "UNC Path".
The connection string "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\Accounts-pc\ACCOUNTS (D)\DATA\RTGS.mdb" is UNC Path for database file named RTGS.mdb.

using the above connection string I am able to read the data but modifying or adding of new record gives this error.

To have a trial I did changed the connection string to "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Data\RTGS.mdb" And run the application where the database server is and I received no errors even for Updating of records.
And because the same was working fine with Windows XP this is clearly because of windows 7 OS that doesnt allowing UNC Path accesing to my databases for Updating records.

SANDEEP

Answer (score 0):

Parens in a path ? That is one difference between your two connection strings. Just a hunch.